# Why DisableBind raise Invalid cursor state error?

Tags: binding, cursor, powerbuilder

When `DisableBind=0` the `Update()` function raise error:

> invalid cursor state

if I set `DisableBind=1` to the `dbparm` before I execute the `Update()` function then everything is fine and the data is saved.

What is the link between `DisableBind` and Invalid cursor state?

I have to use `DisableBind=0`, because I am savings Chinese characters into the DB. What should be the work around?

Environment:
PowerBuilder 12.5
ODBC 11
SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: I suggest you to code a messagebox in the sqlpreview event, showing you the SQL being used.  This will help you to identify the statement(s) causing the invalid cursor state.

Comment: The error is not bound to any specific query and can be raised for a very much valid query but when i set DisableBind=0 just one line before the update() function call i get the same error. The valid query runs into error just because of disablebind and that is why i asked question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the link between DisableBind and Invalid cursor state. But I used a temporary alternative as to set the disablebind parameter only where you need to save unicode characters. Ensure you do not have "disablebind" in your original connection string. If you do, please handle below script accordingly.

```
ls_dbparm = sqlca.dbparm
sqlca.dbparm += ',disablebind=0'
//process your saving code here
//once all saving done, very important to set it back
sqlca.dbparm = ls_dbparm
```

Comment: I know that and my question explained it already. Actually I mean that the DisableBind=1 (always) raise no error and DisableBind=0 (sometimes) raise error. But on many other places before updating Chinese characters i do set DisableBind=0 and there is no error. That is why it is difficult to find why DisableBind=0 raise the invalid cursor state error.